# jQuery submit form, but div flashes and disappears

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm working on a simple form submission. I've made a more complicated code (more entries and variables)exactly like this and it works just fine. When I compare all my code side by side, it is exactly the same, and yet this one won't work! I have the preventDefault(); but that seems to do nothing. I tried the `return false;` which also didn't work. I know it's something simple, but I've been trying to figure it out for a while now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/uppercase.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/uppercase.js"></script>
<title>Uppppppppercase</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Enter whatever you want! The computer will say it back to you!</h1>
    <div class="blanks">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="entry">Enter here!</label>
                <input id="entry" class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn">Let 'er Rip!</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="return">
        <p><span class="entry"></span>HEY</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".blanks form").submit(function(event) {
    var entryInput = $("input#entry").val();
    $(".entry").text(entryInput);
    $("#return").show();
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

And simple css:

```
#return {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: it works, http://jsfiddle.net/GZgz8/. please check yours if it has errors on the console.

Comment: huh. That's crazy, because I've copied and pasted and it does not work at all in my browswer. Just flashes and disappears.